# Thucydides logging - write my logs into the console

Tags: java, logging, thucydides

I would like to be able to write my own log lines into the console log of Thucydides. However, when i try using the log4j, slf4j or Apache commons logging, i can write the Thucydides logs into a file with my log entries, but I cannot see my lines in the console (in Eclipse in my case).

How can I write to Thucydides's console log?

Comment: How do you make it write output to console?

Answer (score 2):

If you use ThucydidesRunner try use this:

1. create field in class:

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThucydidesRunner.class);

2. in test use:

LOGGER.info("My log info");